# Outlook to automatically reply all based on the body

Tags: vba, outlook

well, I do receive lots of emails to release shipments . I want to creat VBA to reply all based on a statement in the email body. Any help ?

Answer (score 0):

The first thing from which you can start is to handle the [NewMailEx](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Outlook.Application.NewMailEx) event of the Application class which is fired when a new message arrives in the Inbox and before client rule processing occurs. You can use the Entry ID returned in the EntryIDCollection array to call the [NameSpace.GetItemFromID](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.namespace.getitemfromid) method and process the item.

This event fires once for every received item that is processed by Microsoft Outlook. The item can be one of several different item types, for example, `MailItem`, `MeetingItem`, or `SharingItem`. The `EntryIDsCollection` string contains the Entry ID that corresponds to that item.

As soon as you have got an item you may check the message body represented by the `HTMLBody` or just `Body` which returns a plain text string that represents the message body.

The [ReplyAll](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.replyall(method)) method creates a reply to all original recipients from the original message. A `MailItem` object that represents the reply is returned. Finally, use the `Send` method to submit the reply for processing.